# Using XSL template in HTML via PHP - correct method

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

I have an XML feed (feefo) that I want to incorporate into an existing web page. I have the feed, I have an xsl file, and a vendor php file that invokes the transformation process. I'm using the following in my html to include the vendor php file:

```
<?php include('feefo/feefofeedback-v2.php') ?>
```

the script vendor php file like this:

```
<?php
$curdir = getcwd();

$merchantidentifier = array_key_exists('merchantidentifier', $_GET) ? $_GET['merchantidentifier'] : 'smartmoneyonline';
$limit = array_key_exists('limit', $_GET) ? $_GET['limit'] : null;
$mode = array_key_exists('mode', $_GET) ? $_GET['mode'] : null;
$vendorref = array_key_exists('vendorref', $_GET) ? $_GET['vendorref'] : null;
$suppressnegatives = array_key_exists('suppressnegatives', $_GET) ? $_GET['suppressnegatives'] : null;

$xml_filename = "http://cdn2.feefo.com/api/xmlfeedback?merchantidentifier=".$merchantidentifier;
if ($limit)
  $xml_filename .= "&limit=".$limit;
if ($vendorref)
  $xml_filename.="&vendorref=".$vendorref; 
if ($mode)
  $xml_filename.="&mode=".$mode; 
if ($suppressnegatives)
  $xml_filename.="&negativesanswered=true";

if (phpversion() < "5"){
  $xmldoc = domxml_open_file( $xml_filename);
  $xsldoc = domxml_xslt_stylesheet_file ( $curdir."/feefo/feedback.xsl");
  $result = $xsldoc->process($xmldoc);
  echo $result->dump_mem();
}
else
{
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
  $doc->load($curdir."/feefo/feedback.xsl");
  $xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);
  $doc->load($xml_filename);
  echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
}

?>
```

Though it works, I'm not sure I'm implementing this correctly because the xsl file includes html, head, body etc. Here's the beginning of the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
 <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:variable name="feefostarsimageroot" select="'http://cdn.feefo.com/feefo/resources/images/rating'" />
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>FeeFo Feedback</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemscope="itemscope">
 <!-- tr class=row -->
       <div class="comments">

           <xsl:for-each select="FEEDBACKLIST/SUMMARY">
               <h1><span itemprop="name">......
```

Obviously the page doesn't validate because I have the parent html, head, body elements, as well as those contained in the xsl file. If I remove those elements in the xsl file, the xml feed no longer works as I get:

> Message: DOMDocument::load(): Namespace prefix xsl on for-each is not defined

Have I approached this in the right way? If so, how do I remove the offending elements from the xsl file and still have it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:variable name="feefostarsimageroot" select="'http://cdn.feefo.com/feefo/resources/images/rating'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <div id="page" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemscope="itemscope">
 <!-- tr class=row -->
       <div class="comments">

           <xsl:for-each select="FEEDBACKLIST/SUMMARY">
               <h1><span itemprop="name">......

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />` is a problem as that would belong into the `head` section of your complete HTML document, you would need to adapt your PHP to make sure you have the CSS link included earlier in your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Bear with me, I have a limited grasp of PHP. I think I see that the php is saying load the stylesheet from the xsl file. If I remove that line (anticipating no style) I get an error: "No stylesheet associated to this object". So I assume the xslt processor won't allow me to include the styles in a regular stylesheet in html. I also can't replace the stylesheet object in PHP with a path to style.css. Would you be able to provide an example of how to load the stylesheet in PHP?

Comment: No, the PHP code you have shown is simply used to load and execute the XSLT, so don't change that, as you want to apply the XSLT. The only problem you have is that the XSLT originally output a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`, presumable to style the elements output by the XSLT. This is no longer possible, so you will have to find the position elsewhere in your (HTML or PHP) code, where the HTML `head` is, and make sure you insert or output the `link` element there.

Comment: So I have added the `<link>` element to the `<head>`, and the styles are applied as expected. But, I still get a PHP errors `Message: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/feefo/feedback.xsl line 1 element stylesheet` and `Message: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:version is missing: document may not be a stylesheet`. Does this mean the XSLT processor is configured the styles in the way they were originally referenced?

Comment: I think I simply made a mistake in the code sample. Please try the edited sample.